# How to implement several same functions on several data frames and retrieve the output to several data frames

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, csv

I have 16047 csv files which I loaded in my global environment in R using tor() function. So now I have 16047 data frames (named like LR1, LR2, ....LR16047) each with two columns. Now I want to do some work on all the data frames.

My data frame looks like this:

```
 V1                                           V2
 
 suff_extn_AACCATTGGCTTTGTGCCATCGGCGGAAGTG_0  T
 suff_extn_AAAGGTCGCCACCATTTCCGGCAGCGATGCT_0  AAAACCTGGCTGCTGGCTCAGGCCGATTTTC
```

This is the code which I want to apply to all the data frames.

```
 pref_LR1 <- LR1 %>% separate(V1, c("Column1", "Column2", "MacroNode", "Column4"))
 pref_LR1$Column1 <- NULL
 pref_LR1$Column2 <- NULL
 pref_LR1$Column4 <- NULL
```

So I am creating new data frames for each existing data frame and separating the first column and then deleting three of the columns.

Is there a way to write in R like we usually do in other programming languages like a for loop and accessing them like [i] for the i-th data frame.

I was trying to do something mentioned in applying same function on multiple files in R

like this

```
# Create vector of file names in working direcotry
  files <- list.files() 
  files <- files[grep("csv", files)]  

#create empty list
 lst <- vector("list", length(files))

#Read files in to list
 for(i in 1:length(files)) {
   st[[i]] <- read.csv(files[i])
 }

#Apply a function to the list
  l <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
   //the work of the function
   return(x)
  })
```

But this is not giving me separate data frames like I want.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming `st[[i]]` is a typo and you actually have `lst[[i]]`. Then the final `l` object will contain all the data.frames. You can access them with `l[[1]]`, `l[[2]]`,  `l[[3]`, etc... (note the double brackets when extracting from a list). Having all your data in a list makes it much easier to work with rather than creating several thousand variables in your global environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can create name of dataframes using `paste0` and use `mget` to get them in a list.

```
list_df <- mget(paste0('LR', 1:16047))
```

It is easier to operate on multiple dataframes when they are in a list. You can then apply your function to each of the dataframe with `lapply`. I think your `separate` call can be simplified with some regex instead of creating 4 columns and then deleting 3 of them but since we don't know how your data looks like I'll not modify it.

```
new_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {
     x1 <- tidyr::separate(x, V1, c("Column1", "Column2", "MacroNode", "Column4"))
     x1$Column1 <- NULL
     x1$Column2 <- NULL
     x1$Column4 <- NULL
     x1
   })
```

This will give you list of dataframes in `new_df`, if you want the changes to reflect in your original dataframe you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(new_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah Thanks for the help. While using the code I found out some of the LR values are missing in my file. So while I am writing the code                                            
         list_df <- mget(paste0('LR', 1:16047)) I am getting an error like LR57 is not found. Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Ashi Yes, if not all values are present you can do `list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = 'LR\\d+'))`

Comment: thanks for that. It worked. Since you said I can use some other function for separating. I am having an error while running the tidyr::separate(x, V1, c(....)) line as while loading the csv into my global environment using tor() function the header was taken as the first row of my datasets. I have edited the post and shown there how my data looks like so is there any other way I can do that.

Comment: @Ashi Don't change this question please. If you need help improving your current code or any other request consider to ask a new question. Each question should solve only one specific problem and not multiple ones.